# Finding appropriate $\delta$ to prove continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 5}$ is continuous at $x = \pi$ using the epsilon delta definition.

Here's how far I could go:

$|x - \pi| < \delta$ is same as $|x^2 - \pi^2| < \delta|x+\pi|$
and this condition should imply $|\frac{x^2 - \pi^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 5} + \sqrt{\pi^2 + 5}}| < \epsilon$ (after rationalising)

I don't how to choose $\delta$ in order to prove what's required. 
Could someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, a little late, but I just figured how to go about it myself so I'll post an answer for completeness:

$|\frac{x^2 - \pi^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 5} + \sqrt{\pi^2 + 5}}| <|\frac{x^2 - \pi^2}{x + \pi}| < |x - \pi| < \delta$ and choosing $\delta = \epsilon$ completes the proof!

Comment: Clever! Your brain is made for analysis :)

Answer (score 2):

You know the denominator is always greater than or equal to $\sqrt{\pi^2+5}$, so observe
$\big|\frac{x^2-\pi^2}{\sqrt{x^2+5}+\sqrt{\pi^2+5}}\big|\le\big|\frac{x^2-\pi^2}{\sqrt{\pi^2+5^2}}\big|$. Then choose $\delta>0$ such that $|x^2-\pi^2|<\epsilon\sqrt{\pi^2+5^2}$.

Comment: Yay, that's an alternative to my method!